# Consistent input model validation error reporting

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Let's say I have the following input model:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

When the birthday field is not provided then I get the following appropriate response:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-818caf3d757ae345a735fd0f4a523ecb-e9f90641c111814c-00",
    "errors": {
        "Birthday": [
            "The Birthday field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

But if I provide an invalid date string, then the following is returned:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-715471c843155940a6f0cae580cd1b69-247e6dbfe3442446-00",
    "errors": {
        "model": [
            "The model field is required."
        ],
        "$.birthday": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]. Path: $.birthday | LineNumber: 13 | BytePositionInLine: 37."
        ]
    }
}
```

These two response models are not consistent which makes it difficult for the client to reason about the validation errors.

How can I validate the DateTime string before it gets handled by the converter so that I can return a response model similar to the first?  Something like this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-818caf3d757ae345a735fd0f4a523ecb-e9f90641c111814c-00",
    "errors": {
        "Birthday": [
            "The Birthday field is badly formed."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I validate the DateTime string before it gets handled by the
> converter so that I can return a response model similar to the first?

You can create a custom BadRequest method that inherits **`ValidationProblemDetails`** to return the error message you want.

First, add the following code in your `startup.cs ConfigureServices` method:

```
 services.AddMvc() 
               .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
               {
                   options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
                   {
                       var problems = new CustomBadRequest(context);
                       return new BadRequestObjectResult(problems);
                   };
               });
```

Here is the custom Bad Request method:

```
public class CustomBadRequest : ValidationProblemDetails
    {
        public CustomBadRequest(ActionContext context)
        {
            Title = "Invalid arguments to the API";
            Detail = "The inputs supplied to the API are invalid";
            Status = 400;
            ConstructErrorMessages(context);
            Type = context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        }
        private void ConstructErrorMessages(ActionContext context)
        {
            foreach (var keyModelStatePair in context.ModelState)
            {
                var key = keyModelStatePair.Key.Replace("$.", "");
                var errors = keyModelStatePair.Value.Errors;
                if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (errors.Count == 1)
                    {
                        var errorMessage = GetErrorMessage(key, errors[0]);
                        Errors.Add(key, new[] { errorMessage });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var errorMessages = new string[errors.Count];
                        for (var i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
                        {
                            errorMessages[i] = GetErrorMessage(key,errors[i]);
                        }
                        Errors.Add(key, errorMessages);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        string GetErrorMessage(string key, ModelError error)
        {
            if (error.ErrorMessage != $"The {key} field is required.")
            {
                return $"The {key} field is badly formed.";
            }
            return error.ErrorMessage;

        }
    }
```

After the above settings, when your InputModel is illegal, it will automatically enter the `CustomBadRequest` method and return the corresponding error message through judgment.

Here is the test result through postman:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the datatype of the datetime field like as follows:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.  I believe the [DataType] attribute has another purpose.